# Fields and the way they should be looked at

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

When I think about the electrostatic interaction and interaction of charged particles having
uniform velocities sometimes I do find it giving rise to a picture of superluminal communication which seems paradoxical . Although I do not exactly know how to resolve this paradox (and would definitely expect some answer to contain a way to guide me through this 
) but I know for sure that I am missing something about the concept of field.
Is it so that the field remains eternally attached to a charged particle and always moves along with it as if like a mass-less dark matter attached to it but capable of carrying energy.And how does an external force which sets the particle into motion with a velocity ,say V , adds up a new kind of field to it which we can analogously say as a new form of mass-less dark matter . (I hope it's clear that the usage of term dark matter is just for the purpose of analogy and I am well aware of the level of audacity it would be associated with If I were proposing that electric field is a dark matter attached to it ).
And how we can extend this electric field to get yet another form of dark matter the induced electric field ?

I felt it's extremely necessary that I get the correct physical picture of fields as :
1. I am unable to be assured by the classical EMT ,which I feel might be due to a misconception about fields as physical entity
2: I guess the advanced theories of physics like QED lay more stress on fields rather than on matter ,and model the fields in a quantum mechanical manner .

My gratefulness for answers is assured.

Answer (score 0):

The change to the field is not instantaneous.  If you had a big magnet on the moon and somebody moved it, our instuments would show its location change at the same time we see (through a telescope) the movement.